# Installing wordpress in subdirectory

Tags: laravel, wordpress, laravel-blade, subdirectory

I am looking to install wordpress into a subdirectory. I currently have a /blogs route and am looking to install wordpress in there.

How do i not lose the blog posts I already have that are generating traffic?

I am using laravel for the website ( I do not want to do a headless cms for this)

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You will have to either keep your URL structure so google does not have to look for new links, or you could 301 redirect every single one of the pages.